# calling stored procedure in laravel shows error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, stored-procedures, procedure

i converted an sql query which i stored a sp and gave it name Sp_Available_Rooms

```
$roomtypes = DB::select("CALL Sp_Available_Rooms()");
```

i get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1318 Incorrect
>   number of arguments for PROCEDURE clickgo.Sp_Available_Rooms; expected
>   1, got 0 (SQL: CALL Sp_Available_Rooms())

Please, could anyone help ?

Comment: You could try to adjust the html by adding [] to the input something like this: `<input type="text" name="foo[]" />`

Comment: i didnt get you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any parameters then use this:

`DB::select('EXEC Sp_Available_Rooms');`

With Parameters:

`DB::select('EXEC Sp_Available_Rooms("param1", "param2", ..)');`

Comment: its not working. the following error shows "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXEC Sp_Available_Rooms' at line 1 (SQL: EXEC Sp_Available_Rooms"